# Why are my variables in my struct changing?

Tags: c, memory, struct, intel

I am trying to set up an SD card on an Intel Board D2000 Quark. The problem, I am encountering is that my variables in my struct change at a certain point in the program. I figured out when the variables are changing but I do not have an idea how to fix it.

The reason I am using C instead of C++ is that the compiler of Intel Microcontrollers Studio does not let my use C++.

Below, I copied some of the relevant code.

```
SD* sdCard;
uint8_t readData(uint32_t block, uint16_t offset, uint16_t count, uint8_t* dst){
    if(count == 0){
        return true;
    }
    if((count + offset) > 512){
        goto fail;
    }
    if(!sdCard->inBlock_ || block != sdCard->block_ || offset < sdCard->offset_){
        sdCard->block_ = block;
        if(sdCard->type_ != SD_CARD_TYPE_SDHC){
            block <<=9;
        }
        uint8_t result = sendCommand(CMD17, block);
        if(result){
            goto fail;
        }
        if(!waitStartBlock()){
            goto fail;
        }
        sdCard->offset_ = 0;
        sdCard->inBlock_ = 1;
    }

    for(; sdCard->offset_ < offset; sdCard->offset_++){
        spiRecieve();
    }
    for(uint16_t i = 0; i < count; i++){
        dst[i] = spiRecieve();
    }
    sdCard->offset_ += count;
    if(!sdCard->partialBlockRead_ || sdCard->offset_ >= 512){
        readEnd();
    }
    QM_PUTS("RD FINISH");
    return true;

    fail:
    QM_PUTS("RD FAIL");
    return false;}
```

The moment the variables change is `sdCard->block_ = block;`. First it is a certain value. After this statement the value is 0xFFFFFFFF; This happens to every variable in the struct.

My struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct SDcard{
uint32_t block_ ;
uint8_t errorCode_;
uint8_t inBlock_;
uint16_t offset_;
uint8_t partialBlockRead_;
uint8_t status_;
uint8_t type_;
}SD;
```

Update for the comments:
This is my temporary main:

```
SD sdCard;

int main(void)
{
if(!SDInit(&sdCard)){
    QM_PRINTF("ERROR1\n");
}
while(1){}
}
```

If anyone knows a solution or has some questions, please let me know.

Comment: Where is the `sdCard` variable coming from?

Comment: The sdCard variable is declared above the function, so it is global to all functions.

Comment: Did you properly malloc that? If that is your entire declaration and it is not declared elsewhere, then you are gonna need `SD * sdCard = malloc(sizeof(SD));`

Comment: Where is the memory for the `SD` object that `sdCard` is pointing at?  If you pointed it at a local variable inside a function that later returned earlier in your program, then it might be aliasing onto local variables on the stack inside your function which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: The first declaration is in the main `SD sdCard;` I give the variable to a function and the function saves it in the library. `SDInit(&sdCard)` `uint8_t SDInit(SD* sd){
 sdCard = sd;//rest of the code}`

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say that you are misusing the SDInit function and sdCard is not properly initialized. Can you show the call to that function, as well as the initialization of the param you pass to it?

Comment: `if(!SDInit(&sdCard)){ QM_PRINTF("ERROR1\n");`: errors are usually reported as non-zero.  That looks weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are improperly initializing `sdCard`. Currently you are assigning the value of `sdCard` to be a pointer to its own location on the stack. Instead, do `SDInit(malloc(sizeof(SD)));`.

Personally, I would not even have that initialization function. I would just do `SD * sdCard = malloc(sizeof(SD));`

EDIT: In response to Peter's point, you could also do this and ignore the instantiation function:

```
SD sdCard;
```

Comment: Thank you! I used your first suggestion because I quite need the function. I am currently testing the system, but at the moment it is working.

Comment: Great. If it ends up working, mark it for others with the same/similar problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Bolt123:  Why would you use dynamic storage for this at all, instead of making `SD sdCard;` instead of `SD *sdCard`?  If you always init a pointer once at startup with a fixed-size malloc call and never change it, you might as well just use static storage instead.  Then you can remove a level of indirection instead of having a pointer that's initialized to point at a private static `SD` object.  You can still pass around a pointer to the static object of course, so you don't have to change much code.

Comment: @PeterCordes, thank you for saying that. I checked my code and I changed it and it is also working. So both of your answers work!

Comment: @Bolt123: yeah, of course Zachary's answer works, it's just less efficient.